# Gerrit API to create changes without having to install git on the webserver?

Tags: php, gerrit

I need to create a PHP webpage which can push changes to gerrit, but ideally without having to install git on the PHP webserver, or cloning the repo.

I need the ability to merge branches, edit files, and create tags.

The Gerrit "inline edit" REST API is the closest I have found. But from what I can tell it only edits files. I can't find any documentation suggesting it supports merge or tag.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [edit file](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12/rest-api-changes.html#put-edit-file) REST API, the [`/projects`](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12/rest-api-projects.html) endpoint offers to create branches and tags.

In combination, this should allow you most of the Git operations.

Honestly, I still think that it might be the better guess to use `git` commands instead of dealing with the REST API, if you have more than a straight-forward process in mind.

Comment: The projects endpoint can create branches, but I can't find anything that suggests it can create tags or merge branches?

It is a straight forward process I need to implement, and I would like to avoid cloning 100's of megabytes of git repos to the web server to do it. (Performance and disk space reasons)

Comment: Ah, indeed, I overlooked that there's no `POST` for creating tags. Crafting a merge commit with the API seems not directly possible.